# Postgresql insert multiple columns malformed array literal

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2, postgresql-10

I am following a tutorial from [here](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-python/insert/), and trying to adapt it to pass multiple column values. I've tried solving this by researching the error message but every time I've tried re-writing the values with a `{` I get a different set of errors. What am I doing wrong?

> DataError: malformed array literal: "value1" LINE 1: ...
>   public."Texas"(licensenum,businessowner) VALUES ('value1','...
>                                                                ^ DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.

My Code:

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost",database="postgres", user="postgres", password="supershinypwdhere")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.executemany("insert into public.\"Texas\"(licensenum,businessowner) VALUES (%s,%s)", [('value1','value2'),('value3','value4')])
conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Can you post your schema?

Comment: @Selcuk Im afraid I dont know how to do that. Is the CREATE statement sufficient?

Comment: Yes but never mind. I was going to check if one of the columns is an array but @klin got it already :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message means that the columns `licensenum` and `businessowner` (or one of them) are arrays. Probably they should be simple text, then your program would work well. However, if you really want them to be arrays, then you should pass lists, not strings as arguments, e.g.:

```
cur.executemany(
    "insert into public.\"Texas\"(licensenum,businessowner) VALUES (%s,%s)", 
    [(['value1'],['value2']),(['value3'],['value4'])])
```

Comment: went back and checked yep I had set the licensenum column to be an array...doh